# npx expo run:android not wokring on m1 mac

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

So I have ejected an expo app to a normal react native app. The IOS version of the app is working fine. But I can't seem to start the android version.

I am getting this error log:

```
› Skipping dev server
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionGradleServices.createOutputFilesRepository().
   > Failed to create parent directory '/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/.gradle' when creating directory '/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: /Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/platforms/android/gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (/Users/moemenhussein/Documents/Projects/ahmo/restart-lifestyle/restart-lifestyle/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/run/android/runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I have already removed my `package-lock.json`, `node_module` etc. I really do not know what to do.